# Python/MySQL - Exportando arquivos CSV

Tags: mysql, python, csv

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para extrair arquivos do meu banco de dados, em csv. O arquivo é gerado normalmente com os dados que estão no banco, mas se eu inserir mais dados dentro do banco, ele gera o mesmo arquivo, somente com oq tinha antes.
Segue o código abaixo:

```
import pymysql
from pymysql import InternalError
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import *

tess = Tk()
tess.title("tess")


def exp_rel_emp():

    conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", password="", db="omnia")
    print("connect sucessfull!")

    try:
        with conn:
            conn.commit()
            statm = "SELECT * FROM omniacademp INTO OUTFILE '/TEMP/CadastroEmpresas.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY ''"
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            with cursor:
                cursor.execute(statm)
                results = cursor.fetchall()
                print(results)
    except InternalError:
        Path('/TEMP/CadastroEmpresas.CSV').touch()
    finally:
        conn.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")


bt = Button(tess, text="tess", command=exp_rel_emp)
bt.place(x=10, y=10)


tess.mainloop()
```

Comment: E se excluir o arquivo manualmente e executar o SQL, o que acontece?

Comment: Ele gera um novo atualizado, mas gostaria que ele sobrescrevesse o anterior, atualizado.

Comment: Basta excluir o arquivo antes. Conforme a própria [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html), a instrução `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` não sobrescreverá o arquivo por questões de segurança.

Comment: A causa  pode ser que o código que gera o arquivo não está sendo executado outra vez depois da inserção de novos dados no banco 
ou está sendo executado  mas está programado para ler apenas os dados existentes no momento em que foi criado não atualizando

Comment: Tem a questão que tem que ter permissão para escrever arquivos no diretório **"/TEMP/"**

Answer (score 0):

Vide a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html):

> *The `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'` form of `SELECT` writes the selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. **`file_name` cannot be an existing file**, which among other things prevents files such as /etc/passwd and database tables from being modified.*

O arquivo que será gerado não pode existir devido, entre outros motivos, questões de segurança, para não correr o risco de sobrescrever arquivos fundamentais do sistema.

Ou seja, se o arquivo existir, basta removê-lo antes de executar a consulta. Utilizando a biblioteca `pathlib` você pode utilizar o método `pathlib.Path.unlink`.